# RecurringApplicationCharge charging

Tags: shopify

Using oauth we are getting the shop's token with the purpose of using it for creating bills using shopify_api. We successfully create ApplicationCharge and RecurringApplicatiomCharge. The user can confirm or deny that request. But we have a question regarding the RecurringApplicationCharge: will the shopify notify our backend at each withdrawal of money for subscription from the account ? Or should we check the withdrawal fact using API in order to know to prolong the subscription or not?

Answer (score 1):

The charge object has the following attributes:

```
billing_on
trial_ends_on
activated_on
cancelled_on
```

Reading the [documentation](https://docs.shopify.com/api/reference/recurringapplicationcharge):

> `billing_on` The date and time when the customer will be billed. The
>   API returns this value in ISO 8601 format.

If you periodically update the charge you can check the next `billing_on` value. Just be sure to keep checking, if you forget to you won't be able to see previous dates.

There don't seem to be any webhooks for payment notifications of apps.